# mysql order by field with NULL values last

Tags: php, mysql

I have been having an issue when using the FIELD function in my order by clause.

My situation is a product can have three categories and the user can choose what category to show first. So there are three possible queries that can be formed. These are:

**Query 1**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    main_categories_id = 2
ORDER BY FIELD(product_condition,
        'graded',
        'new',
        'used');
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    main_categories_id = 2
ORDER BY FIELD(product_condition,
        'new',
        'graded',
        'used');
```

**Query 3**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    main_categories_id = 2
ORDER BY FIELD(product_condition,
        'used',
        'new',
        'graded');
```

This does not work well when the product condition is NULL because it always shows the rows with a NULL value first. I need these to appear last.

I have tried adding NULL to the FIELD function but this doesnt seem to work.

Does anyone know a way I can achieve this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can either:

1. Explicitly sort first by whether the column is `NULL` and *then* by its value:

   ```sql
   ORDER BY product_condition IS NULL, FIELD(...)
   ```

   This works because `product_condition IS NULL` will be 0 for non-`NULL` columns and 1 for `NULL` columns; and in the (default) ascending order, the former will obviously come first.
2. Rely on the fact that `NULL` is sorted last in descending orderings and reverse the arguments to `FIELD()`:

   ```sql
   ORDER BY FIELD(product_condition, ...) DESC
   ```

Answer (score 2):

you should use 'ORDER BY FIELD desc' to display the null values at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try This...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE main_categories_id = 2 ORDER BY CASE WHEN  product_condition IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,FIELD( product_condition, "graded", "new", "used" );
```

same for other two...

Answer (score 1):

Null in the last.
Actual Table

```
+------+---------+
| col1 | col2    |
+------+---------+
| 1    | Closed  |
| 2    | Open    |
| 3    | Pending |
| 4    | New     |
| 5    | NULL    |
| 6    | Closed  |
| 7    | New     |
| 8    | NULL    |
+------+---------+
```

select * from testing2 order by case when col2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, FIELD(col2,'New','Open','Closed','Pending');

```
+------+---------+
| col1 | col2    |
+------+---------+
| 4    | New     |
| 7    | New     |
| 2    | Open    |
| 1    | Closed  |
| 6    | Closed  |
| 3    | Pending |
| 5    | NULL    |
| 8    | NULL    |
+------+---------+
```